# Jquery Dialog box does not appear as soon as it is opened in google chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to open a verifying permission dialog box which shows whether the user has permission or not and also shows progress icon.

In IE and Google chrome, the problem is the dialog box does not appear as soon as it is opened, but appears only when all the permissions are verified.
In fire fox this works correctly.

Here is the img of the dialog box as to how it appears.

[image]

Here is the code

```
var StartVerifyingPermission = function (serverId) {
    $("#dialog-message").removeAttr("title").attr("title", "Verifying Permissions");
    $("#ui-dialog-title-dialog-message").text("Verifying Permissions");
    var html = ' <table>\
         <tr>\
             <td>Skype for Business Admin</td>\
              <td id="isSkypeForBusinessAdmin">Update Status with ajax</td>\
         </tr>\
         <tr>\
             <td>Compliance Manager</td>\
             <td id="isComplianceManager">Update Status with ajax</td>\
         </tr>\
     </table>';
    var msg = "<div style='background:white'>" + html + "</div>";
    $("#dialog-message").html(msg);

    $("#dialog-message").dialog({
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).css({ 'max-height': 70, 'overflow-y': 'auto' });
        },
        modal: true
    });

    var isSkypeAdmin = CheckPermission("isSkypeForBusinessAdmin", serverId);

    if (isSkypeAdmin) {
        var isComplianceManager = CheckPermission("isComplianceManager", serverId);
    }
    if (isComplianceManager) {

    }
};
    var CheckPermission = function (permissionName, serverId) {

        var tag = '#' + permissionName;
        var progressImage = '<img src="../Images/SplashPageLoader.gif" height="30px"/>';
        var sucessImage = '<img src="../Images/mark_tick.ico" height="30px"/>';
        var failedImage = '<img src="../Images/mark_cross.jpg" height="30px"/>';

        $(tag).html(progressImage);

        var hasPermission = false;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "MyHandlerfile.ashx?cmd=" + permissionName,
            data: {
                serverId: serverId
            },
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $(tag).html(sucessImage);
                    hasPermission = true;
                } else {
                    $(tag).html(failedImage);
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                $(tag).html(failedImage);
            }
        });
        return hasPermission;
    };

    var RegisterTestPermissionsEvent = function () {
        $(".testPermission").live("click", function() {
            var serverId = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
            StartVerifyingPermission(serverId);
        });

    };
```

Comment: Where are you calling `StartVerifyingPermission` and `CheckPermission`?

Comment: Could you create a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Satpal: Sorry abt that.. I have added the relevant calls.

Comment: You are using async: false so your code 'waits' for the request to finish.

Comment: @ThermalCube : I am using async:false because there is a permission check dependency and another permission check can only occur if firs one is passed. Anyway I am opening the dialog before that.